# Javascript: change functions parameters on click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple code that is using the library [Lottie](https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/) for **SVG animations**.

There are **2** animations. I need to make one first **on load** and the second start when **user click** on the button. At the same time when the second animation starts second animation replace the first.

So in my expectations I will need to change the parameter of **JS** function.

Is there any option how can I change **path** parameter in **lottie** function and start the second animation than replace the first animation with the second?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="element">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.7.3/lottie.min.js" integrity="sha512-35O/v2b9y+gtxy3HK+G3Ah60g1hGfrxv67nL6CJ/T56easDKE2TAukzxW+/WOLqyGE7cBg0FR2KhiTJYs+FKrw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**JS:**

```
var element = document.getElementById("element");
var animPath = 'anim/data-1.json'
lottie.loadAnimation({
    container: element, // the dom element that will contain the animation
    renderer: 'svg',
    loop: false,
    autoplay: true,
    path: animPath // the path to the animation json
});


function myFunction() {
    var animPath = 'anim/data-2.json'
}
```

Comment: Unfamiliar with lottie. Try adding a call to `lottie.loadAnimation` inside`myFunction`?

Answer (score 0):

Put your animation code in a function and call it with a default path when the page load. Create a click event and call it with a different path.

```
function runAnimation(animPath) {
  lottie.loadAnimation({
    container: element, // the dom element that will contain the animation
    renderer: 'svg',
    loop: false,
    autoplay: true,
    path: animPath // the path to the animation json
  });
}

runAnimation("anim/data-1.json");

let element = documment.querySelector("clicked element selector");

element.addEventListener("click", () => {
  runAnimation("anim/data-2.json");
})
```

Comment: Not working man. Now first animation will not start and second after click wont start too.